# Why does 'IDriver' not contain a definition for 'Session' when using Neo4j in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j

I'm following this guide [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/get-started/) to help me get started in writing a simple query to retrieve some nodes I have established in a local database.

The NuGet package I'm using says 4.0.0, and the documentation is 1.7. I'm not sure if the 4.0.0 is the server version of Neo4J or the .NET API version.

This block here:

```
public void GetMedicalDevices () {
   string query = "match (n:MedicalDevices) return n";

   using (var session = _driver.Session()) {
      var data = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
      {
         var result = tx.Run( query );
         return result;
      });

   }
}
```

At `_driver.Session()` is where this error is happening I can't figure out.

`CS1061 'IDriver' does not contain a definition for 'Session' and no accessible extension method 'Session' accepting a first argument of type 'IDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I'm not sure what other references I'm missing if any, or if maybe the documentation I'm reading is out of data and `Session()` actually doesn't exist on "IDriver" anymore.

Here's the whole class I'm using to write some foobar code to see some things working.

```
class HelloBoltDriver : IDisposable {

   private readonly IDriver _driver;

   public HelloBoltDriver (string uri, string user, string password) {
      try {
         _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(uri, AuthTokens.Basic(user, password));
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Debug.Log(e.Message);
      }
   }

   public void GetMedicalDevices () {
      string query = "match (n:MedicalDevices) return n";

      using (var session = _driver.Session()) {
         var data = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
         {
            var result = tx.Run( query );
            return result;
         });

      }
   }

   public void Dispose () {
      _driver?.Dispose();
   }

}
```

Comment: The [tag:neo4j] tag says to *"mention the exact version of Neo4j when asking questions"*. Maybe it was renamed to `AsyncSession` and the documentation hasn't caught up?

Comment: I opened the 1.7.2 and 4.0.0 packages and yes, it was renamed. Downgrade to 1.7.2 for now while you follow that guide.

Comment: Oops, forgot. I fixed it. I have the NuGet package v4.0.0, but I'm not sure if that means the server version or that specific API version. All the docs I'm able to dig up seems to be in 1.7.

Comment: According to the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4j.Driver/), 4.0.0 was released 21 days ago so, yeah, the documentation hasn't caught up. Selecting "4.0-preview" from the guide's version selector shows a page that still uses `Session` so that's not going to help.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation of Simple Session as an extension to the main driver is [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/dotnet-driver/4.0/html/e10a3fa4-854c-45a2-1970-cbcfdfe52c52.htm)

You need to install the [Neo4j.Driver.Simple package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4j.Driver.Simple/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like:

```
        private async Task mnu_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("username", "pasSW0rd"));
        IAsyncSession session = driver.AsyncSession(o => o.WithDatabase("neo4j"));
        try
        {
            IResultCursor cursor = await session.RunAsync("CREATE (n) RETURN n");
            await cursor.ConsumeAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            await session.CloseAsync();
        }

        await driver.CloseAsync();
```